# Cannot Export Import Products on Backend Magento

Tags: php, magento, import, export, product

I've tried to export products + category from X magento to Y magento with this https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/import-products.htm

[image]

FYI, the exported files are correct, even XML or CSV type.

---

But, i found error when i importing it. it says i found 84 rows, but it's only Imported 1 records, when i check the Manage Products, none of products is imported. I tried on CSV and XML files, the result are same.

[image: Success]

The magento version of both are similar, any possibilities to debug it?

Comment: Is in your csv file a value named product type?

Comment: have man, all are simple product. @hamidparchami

Answer (score 1):

In your import process 84 records means there is 84 lines in your csv file **not 84 products**!

I guess you're using just one **sku** for all of your products and that's why you have just one imported product. It's good to know that
magento uses `sku` as `ID` to identify products, so you need to assign an **unique sku** to every single product.

### **Update:**

To insert new products by CSV Import check this columns in your csv file.

**Required Product Attributes for New Products (written as they should appear in the CSV file column):**

- **sku**

Stock Keeping Unit - a **unique** value to identify the product. No two items can share the same SKU in Pixafy.

- **_attribute_set**

Unless you have already set up Attribute Sets, set this to "Default"

- **_type**

What type of product is this? Your options are: simple, configurable, virtual, and downloadable. Grouped or bundle products can not be imported at this time and must be created in the Control Panel.

- **name**

The product's name- such as "Magic Wand". This should not be longer than 60 characters

- **description**

The long description with detailed information regarding the product.

- **short_description**

The shorter description that appears to the right of the Product Image on the Product page

- **price**

The amount you are charging your customers for this product before sales or discounts.

- **status**

Is the product Enabled or Disabled? Enabled is 1, Disabled, 2

- **visibility**

How will the customer be able to view this item?

Visible in Catalog and Search = 4

Visible in Catalog =2

Visible in Search = 3

Not visible individually  = 1

- **tax_class_id**

Tax Class ID as set up under Set Up > Tax > Product Tax Classes. By default, Taxable Goods are **2**

- **weight**

Enter a numerical value for the weight of this product. This will be used by any calculated shipping methods.

- **_product_websites**

At this time, your only option is **base**

### **Update 2:**

To learn how to add product images to your csv file, read this post:

[Update Magento products with multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486035/update-magento-products-with-multiple-images/31500329#31500329)

Comment: btw, i have column sku on my csv. and all is unique. How how how now? @hamidparchami

Comment: What do you want to do? You wanna update existing products or insert new products?

Comment: i want to insert new products.

Comment: It says image doesn't exists, but why doesn't exists? because i copied all the media folder to new Magento

Comment: I've added a post link about how to add images to your csv file. read that post carefully please.

Comment: hi, now i don't have error and now 84 records imported, but when i check on Manage products, there is no list of product there